# How to select a unique row derived of multiple max(case when) without using distinct in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, window-functions

I need to select the most recent upload date for different documents per id and I would like there to only be one row per id.

What I am currently doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                tree_date,
                sun_date
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          max(CASE
                  WHEN doc_name LIKE 'tree%' THEN upload_date 
                            END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) tree_date,
          max(CASE WHEN doc_name LIKE 'sun%' THEN upload_date
                            END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) sun_date
   FROM documents
   WHERE doc_name LIKE 'tree%'
     OR doc_name LIKE 'sun%' )
```

This query works and gives me my desired results, but I do not believe I am selecting the max upload date of a document per id in the most efficient manner.  Can anyone suggest a more efficient way preferable without distinct as I believe this slows down the query dramatically.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Hi,   if you have a document type column ( like doc_type  values are = tree, sun, moon, river, flower .. so on ) then you can do just group by on doc_type column & select max (upload_date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want conditional aggregation?

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN doc_name LIKE 'tree%' THEN upload_date END) as tree_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN doc_name LIKE 'sun%' THEN upload_date END) as sun_date
FROM documents
WHERE doc_name LIKE 'tree%' OR
      doc_name LIKE 'sun%'
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems the answer was simple. I needed to do a group by instead of partitioning for each type of document.

Answer (score 1):

use row_number window funtion

```
      select * 
      from (
     select id,doc_name,
     row_number() over(partition by id,doc_name order by upload_date desc) n

     from documents where doc_name like 'tree%' or doc_name like 'sun%'
      ) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using row_number()

```
select * from 
(
select id, row_number() over(partition by doc_name,id order by upload_date desc) as rn
from documents
where doc_name like 'tree%' or doc_name like 'sun%'
A where rn=1
```